# find combination of min/max subtract between 2 arrays matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, min, angle, subtraction

I have two arrays of angles: a=[140 360 170 3]; b= [12 270 0 21]; I need to find combination that will give me minimum when subtracting(/adding) elements of arrays. I'm doing this right now:

```
c = [ones(1,4)*a(1)-b; ones(1,4)*a(2)-b; ones(1,4)*a(3)-b; ones(1,4)*a(4)-b];

cc= abs(c);

[minNumk, minIndkl] = min(cc(:));
[rowk, colk] = ind2sub(size(cc), minIndkl);
cc(rowk,:)=[];
cc(:,colk)=[];

 [min2k,minInd2k]=min(cc(:));
 [row2k, col2k] = ind2sub(size(cc), minInd2k);
 cc(row2k,:)=[];
 cc(:,col2k)=[];

 [min3k,minInd3k]=min(cc(:));
 [row3k, col3k] = ind2sub(size(cc), minInd3k);
 cc(row3k,:)=[];
 cc(:,col3k)=[];
 min4k= cc;
total=minNumk+min2k+min3k+min4k
```

Question. Is there any way of doing it in a more concise way? Also I am thinking do I need to use mod(,360) here?

EDITED: if the element was used(subtracted) then it cannot be used anymore. (Thus,the whole row and column is deleted.)

Thanks in advance!!!

Any advice will be very much appreciated!
Happy 10 000 000! :)

Comment: So for your example `a` and `b` what would the ouput be?

Comment: @LuisMendo ..My actual values are: a =[  64   204   170   115];b =[ 75   274   180   268]; total =10+11+64+159. total=244

Comment: Can you explain how you obtain those 10, 11, 64, 159?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. Is `min(sum(abs(bsxfun(@minus, a, perms(b))), 2))` what you want? Or `min(sum(bsxfun(@minus, perms(b), a), 2))`, since you seem to care about sign

Comment: Elements that give minimum combination are (abs): 64-75=11. 170-180=10; 204-268=64;274-115=159.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to try all **permutations** of one of the vectors and **minimize** (over all permutations) the **sum** (over vector entries) of **absolute values** of the differences between the vectors:

```
result_total = min(sum(abs(bsxfun(@minus, a, perms(b))), 2));
```

To get the invididual differences that minimize the sum of absolute differences:

```
d = bsxfun(@minus, a, perms(b));
[result_total, ind] = min(sum(abs(d), 2));
result_indiv = d(ind,:);
```

If you want to consider the differences to be in the range 0-360, use `mod` (and then you don't need `abs`):

```
d = mod(bsxfun(@minus, a, perms(b)),360);
[result_total, ind] = min(sum(d, 2));
result_indiv = d(ind,:);
```

Comment: That's exactly what I need! Thank you!

Comment: how does the above answer changes if I want to get total=[minNumk min2k min3k min4k], WITHOUT sum. I can't figure it out..thank you!

Comment: I have just realized that above answer gives difference between angle 0 and 300. - 300. when it is 60.what is missing here?

Comment: I think you want `mod`. See edited answer (last part)

Comment: Why should you get 17 for angles 0 and 317? I don't get it. What's the rule?

Comment: please ignore me. it works. I am just too tired basic math skips me! sorry!!